# How do we find the inflection points of g?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Consider the function $g(x)=3x(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

How do we find all the inflection points? 
I found $$g^{\prime\prime}(x)=\frac{2(5x-12)}{3(x-2)^{\frac{4}{3}}}$$ so when I do $g^{\prime\prime}(x)=0$ and when $g^{\prime\prime}$ is undefined, I get $x=12/5$ and $x=2$. Is that correct? 

After that, I replace some numbers lower/higher than $12/5$ and $2$? The thing is I did that, but it turns out I get undefined for $g^{\prime\prime}(1)$, and with $g^{\prime\prime}(2.2)$ and $g^{\prime\prime}(3)$, I get both negative numbers, so it turns out I don't have an inflexion point? Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The inflection points correspond to $g''(x)=0$ that is to say $x=\frac{12}5$ and not $x=\frac{12}{15}$. How did you get this last number ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I think I rewrote it down wrong. I really did get $x=\frac{12}{15}$. Thank you for pointing that out! Anyhow, I still don't know how I'm supposed to find the inflection point after that. I drew the graph of $g''$ and I saw that there should be an inflection point at $x=2$, but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: $g''(x)$ is undefined at $x=2$. $g''(x)=0$ only happens at $x=\frac{12}5$. $g''(x)$ is positive if $x>2$, negative if $x<2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but it looks like the algebra is getting you. You are correct that the second derivative is not defined at $x = 2$. The second derivative of $g$ is certainly *not* undefined at $x = 1$, as the numerator is $-14$ and the denominator is $3$. Additionally, $g^{\prime\prime}(3)$ is strictly positive. This is enough to prove a concavity change of $g$ occurs as $x$ passes $2$. Try again evaluating $g^{\prime\prime}(y)$ for values of $y$ a littler larger and a little smaller than $12/5$ (but not smaller than $y= 2$). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! The denominator I got from plugging $1$ into $3(x-2)^(\frac{4}{3})$ gave me an error on my calculator, though, because $(-1)^(\frac{4}{3})$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah those calculators can be deceiving, but just as sure as $(-1)^{4/3} = \left[(-1)^4\right]^{1/3} = 1^{1/3} = 1$, $g^{\prime\prime}(1)$ is defined. Not sure why you're calculator had a problem with that though...

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been a huge help.